# React Native signed build crash immediately after open on device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My app is crashing when I try to run on my device with the signed release build. For some reason the release build works, the singed don't.

After testing multiple times adb logcat throw me this error::

```
2022-05-19 16:10:10.769 734-734/? E/ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.rasystem.ECC pid = -1
2022-05-19 16:10:10.862 9263-9263/? E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.rasystem.ECC/lib-main flags = 1]
        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.rasystem.ECC-suF7xnHuH0hW1lA4qPO4xg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
        Native lib dir: /data/app/com.rasystem.ECC-suF7xnHuH0hW1lA4qPO4xg==/lib/arm64
     result: 0
2022-05-19 16:10:10.863 9263-9263/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rasystem.ECC, PID: 9263
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libfbjni.so" not found result: 0
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:1098)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:914)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:826)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:773)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:743)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:351)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:318)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
        at com.rasystem.ECC.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:54)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libfbjni.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:928)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1633)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:529)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:110)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:63)
        at com.facebook.soloader.ApplicationSoSource.loadLibrary(ApplicationSoSource.java:91)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:1038)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:914) 
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:826) 
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:773) 
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:743) 
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24) 
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20) 
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:351) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:318) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42) 
        at com.rasystem.ECC.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:54) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:235) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

I've been looking for a solution for days and still can't find nothing related to this error.

My project files:

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */
 
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleAssetName: "app.bundle",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rasystem.ECC"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 58
        versionName '4.2.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-vector-icons'
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-community-async-storage'
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-webview'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ECC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.4",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-jitsi-meet": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.13.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "^26.5.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.63.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out `debug` line:

```
release {
  // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
  // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
  // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // >>>>>> This
  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
}
```

Comment: Nice! In case you want to share APK for internal testing with release mode but without certificate in it, you can activate .debug and deactivate .release.

Answer (score 1):

There can me multiple issue. check your code you may import Hooks (**useState, useEffect**) from development mood.  you can find your problem in android studio.When generate release apk, cehck for debug options and connect your device to android studio. from there you can find the creash reason.

Comment: I provided a crash log in the question which comes from adb logcat inside Android Studio but I can't figure out how to solve the problem